# Eclipse plugin operation does nothing in normal 2019-12 instance, but works fine in rcp debug instance

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to debug a problem with the Eclipse plugin at https://github.com/davidmichaelkarr/e4macs . This is a fork of the original application, which is now unfortunately abandonware.

As Eclipse has moved on with further releases, there have been a small number of issues in the plugin.  I was able to fix the first problem (shown by my diffs with the base repo), but the next problem that appeared around 2019-09 is a little harder to figure out.

Specifically, the "split-window-vertically" command just does nothing when I execute it.  It doesn't matter whether it's bound to a key or executed directly from the "execute extended command" prompt.  Nothing appears in the log about this.

So, I downloaded an instance of the RCP 2019-12 distro and set up to debug this.  I ran an "Eclipse Application" in debug and tested the function.  It worked perfectly fine.  This means that somehow something else that I have loaded in my regular 2019-12 installation is making this function not do anything.

From the Marketplace Client, I tried installing some of the same plugins in the debug instance that I have in my regular instance, but I didn't get very far doing this.  I tried to install the "Spring IDE", but this gave me many errors.  It starts out with "Cannot be completed", and it gave me a long list of "will be uninstalled", "Will be upgraded/downgraded", and "Will not be installed".  All of the Spring features were in the latter list.  I tried to install the "Groovy" plugin, and that gave me several "Missing requirement" errors.

I don't know whether the missing plugins are what is causing the operation to work, and I can't figure out why I can't install the plugins.

I'm not sure what to do here.

**Update**:

A comment pointed out that the way to install plugins in a debug instance is to add plugins to the target platform. I proceeded to do that, and discovered that one of the choices for sets of plugins to use is from an existing installation, which is perfect, because that's exactly what I want the debug instance to use, all the plugins in my existing 2019-12 installation.

Unfortunately, doing this has apparently removed my other installed plugins as the source of the problem.  I tested the plugin code in this newly edited debug instance, which has all of the same plugins as my regular instance, and the plugin is working perfectly fine.  In my regular instance, when I execute the operation in question, nothing happens.  No error of any kind, and I don't get the expected result.  The operation in question is "split-window-vertically", which should do what it sounds like.

Note that by setting the plugin source to the regular installation, that also included the installed copy of the plugin in question, the Emacs+ plugin (which is installed from the "dropins" directory).  I'm not sure exactly what that would do.  In any case, I set breakpoints in the plugin code, and when I executed the operation, it did hit the breakpoints.

Note that I also did import the same preferences file into the debug instance that I use in the regular installation, so the preferences are identical, and based on the previous information, the set of installed plugins should be almost identical (I'm not convinced they are exactly identical).

The only other difference between the debug instance and my regular installation is that the regular installation is the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" variation from the Eclipse installer, but the debug instance was launched from the "Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers" variation.  I have no idea whether that is significant.

**Update**:

I added logger calls to the plugin code (using "org.eclipse.equinox.log.Logger", is that the correct logger class to use?).  I even added a logger call (and even a println) to the constructor of the operation handler class.  None of those were seen in the log file.  That tells me that something is wrong with my plugin configuration files, like the "plugin.xml" file.

The "plugin.xml" file is 3928 lines long, so I'm a bit hesitant to just paste it here.  I tried opening it in Eclipse, and it doesn't complain about anything.

The following is a screen grab showing the relevant entry:

[image]

Note that although the executable operation isn't doing anything, and it seems like the handler isn't being executed, there are some aspects of the operation definition that are being properly loaded into Eclipse, like the description of the operation.  Emacs+ provides a "describe-command" function, and I can specify "split-window-vertically" to this command, and it properly returns the description of this command as set in the "plugin.properties" file.

Also note that although this particular operation is not doing anything in this version of Eclipse, there are other functions in Emacs+ that are still working perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm not sure that trying to install in a debug instance works. The plugins available are controlled by your Target Platform, you would have to update that to include other plugins.

Comment: That was helpful, I suppose, but that only eliminated my installed plugins as the source of the problem.  I updated the target platform to include my 2019-12 installation, so that got all the plugins I'm using, but the symptom doesn't occur in the debug instance, even though it does in my regular 2019-12 instance. I'll update the post with this information.

Comment: I thought of adding logger calls to the operation code and reinstalling the plugin in a local update site, instead of using the dropins folder.  The log strings never appeared in the log. In fact, I added a log call to the constructor of the operation handler class, which also did not appear. This makes me think there is something wrong with my config files, like the plugin.xml file. I will update the post with this, but I think I will have better luck with a new post.